# Razor does not understand ViewBag inside Html.TextBoxFor with or without @ prefix

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Found a new problem so that´s why I´m creating a new post.
Razor engine is not helping me finish my work today..

Using this code I don´t get ViewBag.user.UserName printed in my screen

```
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "validate[required]", disabled = "disabled", value = @ViewBag.user.UserName }) @Html.ValidationMessage("usernameVal", "*")</td>
```

Now, if I put outside the TextBoxFor like that:

```
@ViewBag.user.UserName
```

I get the user username.

Was Razor supposed to be smart enough to detect a situation like that?

Comment: Could you add the error message you're getting?  That would help us narrow down the problem.

Comment: Why don't you simply omit @ in front of `ViewBag` because it's already part of server side code? And if `@class` is the problem, then put `ViewBag` before it...

Comment: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { disabled = "disabled", value = (with or withou @)ViewBag.user.UserName })  -- This does not work too! Also tried: (string)ViewBag.user.UserName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think thats because you are trying to set the value atribute, which razor will set using the model value.

You could however update the model value with the one in the view bag using a code block before calling the helper:

```
@{
    Model.UserName = ViewBag.user.UserName;
}
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "validate[required]", disabled = "disabled" }) @Html.ValidationMessage("usernameVal", "*")</td>
```

But why would you be doing that instead of having the value already in the model?

Comment: The thing is I am not sure how to implement this in my controller. That´s way I am doing this in this ugly way! Could you help me?

Comment: I don´t know what you are doing to populate that in the view bag, but you could do the same in the controller to populate the view model? If it is taken from the Principal\Identity objects, you may be able to create a read only property (no set) in your model?